# Partially processing a conduit using another conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm looking to make a function with the following signature (I think):

```
partialProcessConduit :: forall m a b r. Monad m 
  => (a -> (b, Maybe (ConduitT () a m ()) )) 
  -> ConduitT b Void m r 
  -> ConduitT () a m () 
  -> m (r, ConduitT () a m ())
partialProcessConduit splitFunc consumingConduit sourceConduit
```

Which basically does the following:

1. Repeatedly gets a value of type `a` out of the the conduit `sourceConduit`.
2. Applies the functions `splitFunc` to that value `a`.
3. Pushes the value `b` from `splitFunc` into `consumingConduit`
4. IF `splitFunc` returns `Just (some conduit)` (i.e. not `Nothing`) for the second part of it's returned pair THEN

   1. "close up" `consumingConduit`, and get the result value `r`
   2. Return a conduit with the "rest" of `sourceConduit`, but with conduit in the Just appended in front of it.

I've actually achieved something close to this (apologies in advance for crappy naming). See here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Conduit (ConduitT, SealedConduitT, unsealConduitT, ($$+), await)
import Data.Void (Void)
import qualified Control.Arrow as Arrow
import Data.DList (DList)

partialProcessConduitInMemory :: forall m a b r. Monad m 
  => (a -> (b, Maybe (ConduitT () a m ()))) 
  -> (DList b -> r) 
  -> ConduitT () a m () 
  -> m (r, ConduitT () a m ())
partialProcessConduitInMemory splitFunc collapseDList sourceConduit = do
  (sc :: SealedConduitT () a m (), (result :: r, leftOver :: ConduitT () a m ())) <- x
  pure (result, leftOver >> unsealConduitT sc)
  where
    x :: m (SealedConduitT () a m (), (r, ConduitT () a m ()))
    x = sourceConduit $$+ g
    g :: ConduitT a Void m (r, ConduitT () a m ())
    g = Arrow.first collapseDList <$> go mempty
    go :: DList b -> ConduitT a Void m (DList b, ConduitT () a m ())
    go blockList = await >>= \case
      Nothing -> pure (blockList, pure ())
      Just block -> case splitFunc block of
        (transformedBlock, Nothing) -> go $ blockList <> pure transformedBlock
        (transformedBlock, Just leftOver) -> pure (blockList <> pure transformedBlock, leftOver)
```

This is *almost* what I want. Notice the type signature here is the same as above EXCEPT for the second argument. Here, instead of passing a conduit sink that consumes the elements as the second argument, I'm collecting them in a `DList. I'd rather be able to use a conduit sink to consume the first part of the conduit source, instead of collecting all the elements in a list and processing them.

Am I able to use a conduit sink here instead of the `DList`, and if so, what sort of adjustments do I need to make? I thought about pushing elements into the sink in the `go` loop instead of just appending them, and then doing `runConduit` to get the result `r` somehow, but I wasn't able to play nice with the types. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

partialProcessConduit :: forall m a b r. Monad m
  => (a -> (b, Maybe (ConduitT () a m ()) ))
  -> ConduitT b Void m r
  -> ConduitT () a m ()
  -> m (r, ConduitT () a m ())
partialProcessConduit f snk src = do
  (rest2, (mrest1,r)) <- src $$+ fuseBoth loop snk
  pure (r, maybe id (>>) mrest1 (unsealConduitT rest2))
  where loop :: ConduitT a b m (Maybe (ConduitT () a m ()))
        loop = do ma <- await
                  case ma of
                    Just a -> do
                      let (b, mrest) = f a
                      yield b
                      case mrest of
                        Nothing -> loop
                        Just rest -> pure (Just rest)
                    Nothing -> pure Nothing
```

The `loop` conduit here has type `ConduitT a b m (Maybe (ConduitT () a m ())`, so it inputs `a`s and outputs `b`s until `f` (AKA `splitFunc`) returns a prefix conduit, in which case it returns `Just` that conduit.  If `splitFunc` never returns a conduit, it returns `Nothing`.

Now, we can `fuseBoth loop snk`, which has type `ConduitT a Void m (Maybe (ConduitT () a m (), r)`.  This sinks the `b`s from `loop` into the `snk`, returning both the prefix conduit from `splitFunc`, if any, and the return `r` from `snk`.

Finally, we can `src $$+ fuseBoth loop snk`.  This will run the whole conduit sourcing `a`s from `src` and sinking `b`s into `snk`, until `splitFunc` returns a prefix conduit, at which point it will return:

```
(SealedConduitT () a m (), (Maybe (ConduitT () a m ()), r))
```

where, incredibly, the sealed conduit is what's left of `src`, the `Maybe` conduit is the "prefix" conduit returned by `splitFunc`, and the final `r` is the return value from `snk`.   All that's left is to glue this together into an appropriate return value.

This seems to work as per the following test:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  (r, c) <- partialProcessConduit foo (printC >> pure 999) (yieldMany [1,2,3,4,7,8,9])
  runConduit (c .| printC)
  print r

  where foo 4 = (42, Just (yieldMany [5,6]))
        foo n = (10*n, Nothing)
```

This outputs:

```
λ> main
10
20
30
42
5
6
7
8
9
999
```

which looks right.